# A good method for setting the search scope using radio buttons?

Tags: search-scope, enterprise-search

I am looking for some guidance on a good method to allow the user to set the search scope using radio buttons instead of selecting a scope from the scope pull-down. I am using the SmallSearchInputBox.

One method I thought of was to hide the scopes pull-down with CSS and use the radio buttons to set the pull-down value. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same requirement as yours. can you explain me how you have achieved it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the link. It didn't quite get me to where I wanted to go with this solution but it did give me an idea. I enabled the scopes pull-down and then set the value in the pull-down based on which radio button the user selected using jQuery.

Then I set the style to display: none; on the pull-down. It worked and took very little code.

Answer (score 0):

this is one method you could try using html and javascript:

http://davecavins.com/2011/08/simple-search-box-with-radio-buttons/

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It didn't quite get me to where I wanted to go with this solution but it did give me an idea.